# python intersection initial state standard practice

Tags: python, intersection

Example:

```
complete_dict = dict()
common_set = set()
for count, group_name in enumerate(groups_dict):
    complete_dict[group_name] = dict()  # grabs a json file = group_name.json

    if count > 0:
        common_set.intersection_update(complete_dict[group_name])
    else:
        # this accounts for the fact common_set is EMPTY to begin with
        common_set.update(complete_dict[group_name])
```

WHERE: `dict2` contains k:v of members(of the group): int(x)

Is there a more appropriate way to handle the initial state of the intersection?

I.e. We cannot intersect the first `complete_dict[group_name]` with `common_set` because it is empty and the result would therefore **also** be empty.

Comment: please use lowercase for variable names. Also you can remove every single call to `.keys()`

Comment: ClassName, method_name, VAR_NAME; and I know I don't NEED .keys() (is there an advantage either way of using/not using?)

Comment: ClassName method_name, var_name. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ It is common convention not to use `.keys()` when iterating a dictionary, also it is faster, especially in Python 2 where `.keys()` constructs a list.

Comment: thanks for the info; updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid the special case would be to initialize the set with the contents of the item. Since a value intersected with itself is the value itself, you won't lose anything this way.

Here's an attempt to show how this could work. I'm not certain that I've understood what your different `dict(...)` calls are supposed to represent, so this may not translate perfectly into your code, but it should get you on the right path.

```
it = iter(dict(...)) # this is the dict(...) from the for statement
first_key = next(it)
results[first_key] = dict(...) # this is the dict(...) from inside the loop

common = set(results[first_key]) # initialize the set with the first item

for key in it:
    results[key] = dict(...) # the inner dict(...) again
    common.intersection_update(result[key])
```

As jamylak commented, the calls you were making to the `keys` method of various dictionaries were always unnecessary (a dictionary acts pretty much like a `set` of keys if you don't do any indexing or use mapping-specific methods). I've also given chosen variables that are more in keeping with Python's style (`lowercase` for regular variables, with `CAPITALS` reserved for constants).

Comment: you understood it just fine, sorry for the ambiguity.  I thought my word choice would help make things clearer.  Your answer doesn't avoid a special, first case scenario; your answer just handles it differently.

Comment: @ddenhartog: There's an advantage to handling the special case outside the loop: you don't need to have the condition evaluated on every pass. You know the setup code only needs to run for the first item in the sequence, so it makes sense to handle that item before looping over the rest (which can all be handled the same).

Comment: I like the novel approach.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Blcknght](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16213896/282912)'s answer but with less complexity and repetition:

```
common = None
uncommon = {}

for key in outer_dict:
    inner = uncommon[key] = inner_dict(...)
    if common is None:
        common = set(inner)
    else:
        common.intersection_update(inner)
```

Like Blcknght, it is hard to know if this captures the intent of the original because the variable names are not descriptive nor distinct.

Comment: It does capture the intent.  I'm new to stack, sorry for the confusion with my wording.  What is the advantage of setting inner = uncommon[key] and using inner instead of uncommon[key] for the intersection?  And is the use of `None` more pythonic than count > 0?

Comment: Using `inner =` keeps you from having to repeat `uncommon[key]` twice later which is (minutely) more efficient and more readable; it also gives you a chance to pick a more meaningful name. `None` is a good sentinel value because it keeps you from having to `enumerate` and keeps "magic numbers" (0) out of the code. Although it doesn't apply here, the intersection could be empty but it won't become None again.

Comment: I will remember the None vs. 0 concept, which may come in handy some day.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Logically when we want to assign the output of intersection between several sets, we assign the smallest set (set with minimum length) to the output set and compare other sets with it right?

```
uncommon_result = dict(...)  # a method that returns a dict()
common_set=sorted([(len(x),x) for x in uncommon_result.values()])[0][1]
for a_set in uncommon_result.values():
    common_set.intersection_update(a_set)
```

I know the second line can be one of the worst thing to do to initiate `COMMON_SET` cause it does lots of unnecessary works but mathematically almost all the time we want to know which one of our sets is the smallest, in that case, these works aren't in vain.

EDIT: If uncommon_result is a dict of dicts, you may need to add another for loop to go over its keys and with some minor changes in the above inner for, you'll be good again.

Comment: uncommon is a dict of dicts (one deep).

Comment: You mean uncommon has some dicts and those have some sets right? so what common_set want to be? a set of all intersection or a dict with the intersection of each key in uncommon? Either way, if you want to go with this scenario, you can add another for to go over each key in uncommon.